# compute only diagonal of product of matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Is there an efficient way in Matlab to compute only the diagonal of a product of 3 (or more) matrices?  Specifically I want

```
diag(A'*B*A)
```

When A and B are both very large it can take a long time.  If there are only two matrices

```
diag(B*A)
```

then I can quickly do it this way:

```
sum(B.*A',2)
```

So right now I calculate the diagonal in the case with 3 matrices like this:

```
C = B*A;
ans = sum(A'.*C',2);
```

which helps a lot, but the first operation (C = B*A) still takes a long time.  The whole thing must be repeated a number of times as well, resulting in weeks to run my code.  For example, B is about 15k x 15k and A is about 32k x 15k.  And nothing is sparse.

Comment: With matrices that large and not sparse.... I think you're SOL.

Comment: You mean A is about 15k x 32k, right? ;-)

Comment: It looks like you can't avoid doing the first of the full multiplications (`C` in your code), as all of the elements in `C` are needed in order to do the second multiplication

Comment: Yes, I do mean A is 15k x 32k.  Thanks for finding that mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, welcome! To be honest, this seems to be difficult. A little change is at least slightly increasing the speed:

```
N = 5000;
A = rand(N,N*2);
B = rand(N,N);

t = cputime;
diag(A'*B*A);
disp(['Elapsed cputime ' num2str(cputime-t)]);

t=cputime;
C = B*A;
sum(A'.*C',2);
disp(['Elapsed cputime ' num2str(cputime-t)]);

% slightly better...
t=cputime;
C = B*A;
sum(A.*C)';
disp(['Elapsed cputime ' num2str(cputime-t)]);

% slightly better than slightly better...
t=cputime;
sum(A.*(B*A))';
disp(['Elapsed cputime ' num2str(cputime-t)]);
```

Results:

```
Elapsed cputime 82.2593
Elapsed cputime 28.6106
Elapsed cputime 25.8338
Elapsed cputime 25.7714
```